# Is there a way to read hidden inputs with array-like names correctly in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, html, dom

An interface has a number of hidden inputs called "kilos[]" or "precio[]". These are then passed on to a PHP function that handles them like an array. All that is fine. However, if I require to delete a row (tr) from the table (where the inputs will be deleted, too) then I do the following:

```
var e=t.parentNode.parentNode;
var ix=e.sectionRowIndex;
var p=e.parentNode;
var f2=t.form;
var kl= p.rows.length > 2 ? f2.elements["kilos[]"][ix].value : f2.elements["kilos[]"].value;
var pc= p.rows.length > 2 ? f2.elements["precio[]"][ix].value:f2.elements["precio[]"].value;
f2.tokilos.value-=parseFloat(kl).toFixed(2);
f2.tomonet.value-=parseFloat(pc).toFixed(2);
f2.totamb.value-=parseFloat(kl).toFixed(2);
p.removeChild(e);
```

Notice that this code **only** works in Chrome, nowhere else. Can you see what needs to be done in order to get the correct values of "kilos[]" and "precio[]"?

If the total number of rows left in the table is greater than 2, then I can use:

`f2.elements["kilos[]"][ix].value`

However, if the number of rows is not greater than 2, I need to do this, instead:

`f2.elements["kilos[]"].value`

That is the only way for it work and only in Chrome. sectionRowIndex returns the correct values all the time; it is the `form.elements["name[]"][ix].value` that by itself does not behave as expected when the number of rows in the tbody is only 1 (the last one). The code works and does what I need it to be done; however, it is odd that such a workaround is needed.

Is there a way to make this work in all browsers, using pure javascript?

Comment: FYI, `sectionRowIndex` and `rowIndex` would be terrible tags. Tags are used to categorize questions and allow us to follow tags by interest. Who do you think would be interested in "rowIndex"? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`document.getElementsByName('kilos[]')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) which will always return an array-like object.

If you want to restrict the search to a specific element, you can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll):

```
var inputs = f2.querySelectorAll('[name="kilos[]"]');
// or
 var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#formID [name="kilos[]"]');
```

Comment: However, the question here is why form.elements["name"][index] **only** works correctly if the tbody contains more than 1 row. Also, it only works in Chrome. Is JavaScript still so far from a trustable standard?

Comment: @user3599566: That has nothing do with JavaScript, it's the DOM interface. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#htmlformcontrolscollection-0. Basically it formalizes that if there is only one element with the given name, it should be returned.

Comment: Also, I need to find the elements (the array) INSIDE a form, not inside the document; the user might have more than one form (different ID each) opened. I have not been able to find form methods that will find elements by name; but I am trying as of now. If my SPA were only 1 document, that would work; but any number of identical forms (with different data) can be opened at any one time.

Comment: The following has just worked perfectly for me!  `var kl= f2.querySelectorAll('[name="kilos[]"]')[ix].value;
var pc= f2.querySelectorAll('[name="precio[]"]')[ix].value;`

Comment: No worries, at least you can "accept" the answer by clicking the tick outline next to it.

Comment: However, does not work in IE W8.1 latest update. ---------------------------
Mensaje de página web
---------------------------
Error: No se puede obtener la propiedad 'value' de referencia nula o sin definir Script: Line: 151 Column: 2 StackTrace: TypeError: No se puede obtener la propiedad 'value' de referencia nula o sin definir
---------------------------
Aceptar   
---------------------------

Comment: And it does not work in Mozilla Firefox: Error: TypeError: f2.querySelectorAll(...)[ix] is undefined Script:  Line: 151 Column: 9 StackTrace: TypeError: f2.querySelectorAll(...)[ix] is undefined

Comment: Maybe your selector is incorrect or `ix` is out of bounds.

Comment: Felix Kling: I am using IDENTICAL VALUES and code and files for all tests. So, why would my selector or my ix value be OK under Chrome, but out of bounds for IE or Firefox? IX has exactly the same identical value for the tests being done with all 3 browsers. I just checked Chrome in Adroid and It worked just fine! I was about to test the iPad but it is upgrading itself just now! This thing is telling me not to comment any more. This is scary. I tried to move it to chat but I am an underprivileged mortal.